# How can I store the value from recognized text in this Tesseract.recognize in javascript

Tags: javascript, tesseract.js

I want to store the value of the `finallext` in a variable and print it in a text box how can I do it? Can anybody help me with this????

```
Tesseract.recognize(
    '../uploads/scanned-images/<?php echo $image_name; ?>',
    'eng',
        { logger: m => console.log(m) }
        ).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
            var extractedText = text;
            var finalText = extractedText.replace(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/gi, '');
            alert(finalText);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return some variables in `then()` like this.

```
const finalText = await Tesseract.recognize(
    '../uploads/scanned-images/<?php echo $image_name; ?>',
    'eng',
        { logger: m => console.log(m) }
        ).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
            let extractedText = text;
            let finalText = extractedText.replace(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/gi, '');
            // alert(finalText);
            return finalText;
    });
alert(finalText);
```

**P.S** You need to use `async function`.